# Can anyone translate this dateformat?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I’m having a problem with date formats.

I need to convert the following string into af date object: **2011-09-19T12:23:51Z**

And then convert the date object back to a string with this format: **19. september 2011**

I can’t figure out what the **“T”** and **“Z”** is all about though?
Can anyone help me?

Kind regards
Jesper

Answer (score 3):

The "T" is to separate the date from the time.

The "Z" shows that this is in UTC.

This is a standard (extended) [ISO-8601 format date/time string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Combined_date_and_time_representations) - it should be easy to parse with whatever libraries iOS provides.